# Definition of Generic function

Tags: programming-languages, python, c, generic-programming

1)

Below is a python function `summation`, that can perform sum of cubes/squares/.., **similar operations**.

```
def identity(k):
    return k

def cube(k):
    return pow(k, 3)

def square(k):
    return pow(k,2)

def summation(n, term):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return term(n) + summation(n-1, term)

def sum_cubes(n):
    return summation(n, cube)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sum = sum_cubes(4)
    print(sum)

 """ In C, We can implement the same using function pointers. Goal is, to    
    perform similar operations(Sum of ..) using single function summation()"""
```

---

2)

Consider, below sorting api from C,

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
                            int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

Here, `qsort` can sort **data of any type**, array of floats/file names in a directory/strings/...

---

Question:

How to define a Generic function?

Is `summation` a generic function?

or

Is `qsort` a generic function?

or

Given two examples, Is *Generic function* an invalid terminology?

*Note: Motivation-To term `qsort` or any sort function that I design*

Comment: What definition of "generic function" have you read that you don't understand? It would help if you posted that instead of writing a bunch of code.

Comment: The type theory term for the kind of genericism where a function works for any type without constraint and without knowledge of the specific type is [*parametric polymorphism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism). The identity function is generic in this manner.

Comment: In some languages (like Java) "generic function" has a specific technical definition. But this is not the case in Python, so "generic function" does not have well-defined meaning. It does not mean it is "invalid terminology", just that you should be aware of the context when you use the term.

Comment: @AndresF.  Javascrpt also uses this *generic function* terminology a lot. Because you may have a function that takes any html element to process(example - delete all children of given html element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several meanings to "generic".

**Informal definition**

["generic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic)  in everyday language something that shares common properties but is less specific in some ways.

Under this perspective, you could consider [`qsort()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) as generic : the code of this function is able to sort any fixed size data structure for which you can define a comparison function by using the QSORT algorithm.

The same applies to your `summation()` function, which summarizes terms obtained using any functions with one parameter.

**Formal definition**

Programming languages like C++ or Java allow for generic programming with the use of templates or generics:

> ***Definition from the C++14 standard:*** A template defines a family of
>   classes or functions or an alias for a family of types.

The principle is that a class or a function's implementation can be parametrized by types.

According to this more formal point of view, `qsort()` is not a generic function.  Its implementation doesn't need to determine any type at compilation, and its behavior is type independent.  The only thing it needs, is the size of the elements being sorted, and this size is an ordinary argument that is processed at run-time.

For [a language that is not statically typed such as Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20449398/3723423), I'm not sure what to answer for `summation()`.  I think it is not generic because its implementation and its behavior is not type dependent : this function is just a function of higher order, with the argument `term` being a function.  It doesn't use any feature that would alter the behavior of this function based on types.

For illustration of a generic function, you could take a look at the C++ standard function [`std::sort()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) :  its implementation depends on the type of its arguments (and optionally a comparison function with arguments of a determined type).  By using the features of C++ templates, it can sort any container of any type, under the condition that it has the operators/member functions/traits/iterators  that are required by the implementation of the generic function.

**Can a dynamic typed language have generic functions**

Dynamically typed language require less generic code than statically typed languages.

For example, if you have a container of objects of dynamic type, a qsort function could generically sort the container, as long as any combination of two elements in the container can be compared.

But even in such a flexible environment, generic --type dependent-- programming could be helpful. The typical use case is multimethods , where the behavior or the code depends on the type of the arguments or even the combination of types (such as for determining the intersection between two different shapes). For additional information see:

- [Generic programming package for python: multidispatching](http://generic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multidispatching.html)
- [Making generic functions usable in smalltalk](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1233349&dl=ACM&coll=DL&CFID=705508189&CFTOKEN=29625222)
- [Example of generic function in Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_function#Common_Lisp)

Comment: Not sure, Why are we comparing [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)(mainly used to avoid type casting in Java & helps performing Polymorphism) with definition of generic function?

Comment: @overexchange I think that java also offers generic programming, including generic methods (see [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4) or [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)).  Nevertheless I've edited slightly the definition part to address your remark.

Comment: The Generic package from Python has nothing to do with generic functions. Except they share the same adjective.

Comment: @Killian if [generic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming#Stepanov.E2.80.93Musser_and_other_generic_programming_paradigms), is about *the idea of abstracting from concrete, efficient algorithms to obtain generic algorithms that can be combined with different data representations*, I think that the multimethods in that package should be in, don't you think so ?

Answer (score 2):

Generic functions take the type of at least one function argument generically at compile time. That is, the compiler finds out which type is used at a certain place and applies exactly this type where it is used in the function. E.g. if you have a generic argument in your function that is used with a `+` operator, the type must have appropriate methods. For strings/arrays this would in many case be a concatenation and for and integer/float an addition. The compiler can detect that an apply the correct operation. Your C routine is not generic in that sense, since it's the programmer that applies some size information and not the compiler detecting the type and using the correct size.

E.g. in some fictive language

```
func add(p1,p2) {
  return p1+p2
}

print add("a", "b") // yields "ab"
print add(1, 2) // yields 3
```

Here the compiler detects in the first case that two strings are applied and will internally expand something like

```
func add(p1:string, p2:string)
```

and treat the `+` as concatenation while in the second case it would expand

```
func add(p1:int, p2:int)
```

as per supplied integer parameters. Generic means, the compiler generates individual code during compile time. Python for example is untyped and would do that kind of substitution during runtime. Means: Python does not have generic functions since everything is sort of generic.

Comment: Did not get your idea. you mean + is a generic function, syntax in C++?

Comment: Function taking function arguments are higher order functions in Python/JavaScript world. In C, we need function pointers, for same.

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: So, what kind of function is `summation`, Higher order function? and nothing more than that?

Comment: As said: your Python does not count. It has no generic function. Or all functions are generic in Python as it's not a typed language. Your example functional is only different as it's recursive. Btw. C also does not know about generics.

Comment: Why should generic necessarily be bound to compile-time typing ? Even in dynamically typed languages you can make an algorithm dependent on the type, and beyond the simple cases of polymorphism.

Comment: @Christophe Generic=creational; the COMPILER will do that for you. Else everything is generic (since YOU create it). See also definition in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_function

Comment: There are lots of definition fo what generic is. Stroustrup for example defines it as "programming using types as parameters".  For the wikipedia reference, I'd rather go to:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming

Comment: @Christophe Makes sense to point to Generic Programming iso. Generic Function where the question is about Generic Function.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to start this from the perspective of C++, then work my way into C.

In statically-typed languages like C, C++, Java, etc., a "generic" function allows you to specify the function operations *once*, using placeholders for any types that may vary between different calls (which means functions like `qsort` and `bsearch` are *most definitely **not*** generic functions).  Ideally, you'd also like the compiler to automagically detect any calls to this generic function and generate the actual code as necessary.

C++ makes this easy<sup>1</sup> by offering *templates*:

```
template <typename T>
T summation( T *values, size_t numValues )
{
  T result = 0;
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < numValues; i++ )
    result += values[i];
  return result;
}
```

`T` is a placeholder for any type<sup>2</sup>, so you can call it as

```
int ivals[]    = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
double dvals[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

int sumi    = summation( ivals, 10 );
double sumd = summation( dvals, 10 );
```

When the code is compiled, the compiler sees the two calls to `summation` and *deduces* the types of the arguments.  For each different type, it *generates* a new instance of the function, giving it a unique name:

```
int summation_i( int *values, size_t numValues )  // actual compilers will generate
{                                                 // more complex "mangled" names
  int result = 0;                                 // than this
  ...
}

double summation_d( double *values, size_t numValues )
{
  double result = 0;
  ...
}
```

It then generates code such that the result of `summation_i` is assigned to `sumi` and `summation_d` is assigned to `sumd`.

C doesn't offer anything similar to the template feature.  Traditionally, we've attacked generic programming in one of two ways - either by using macros or by using `void *` everywhere and delegating type-aware operations to other functions.

Here's a bad example of a macro-based solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SUMMATION_DEF(t) \
t summation_##t( t *values, size_t numValues ) \
{                                              \
  t result = 0;                                \
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < numValues; i++ )     \
    result += values[i];                       \
  return result;                               \
}

#define SUMMATION(t,x,s)  summation_##t(x, s)

SUMMATION_DEF(int)
SUMMATION_DEF(double)

int main( void )
{
  int ivals[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  double dvals[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

  int sumi = SUMMATION(int, ivals, 5);
  double sumd = SUMMATION(double, dvals, 5);

  printf( "sumi = %d\n", sumi );
  printf( "sumd = %f\n", sumd );

  return 0;
}
```

The `SUMMATION_DEF` is *roughly* similar to a template in that it specifies the function operations, using the macro parameter `t` as a type placeholder.  We also use `t` as part of the function name - the `##` is the token pasting operator, and the preprocessor will expand `t` and append that value to the name of the function<sup>3</sup>.

Where it differs from C++ is the fact that a macro is just a dumb text substitution.  It doesn't trigger any special operations on the part of the compiler.  The actual function instances aren't automatically generated based on any invocations of the `SUMMATION` macro - we have to explicitly generate the functions we want (hence the `SUMMATION_DEF(int)` and `SUMMATION_DEF(double)` before `main`).  It also means that when we call `summation_xxx` through the `SUMMATION` macro, we have to pass the type as part of the macro argument list, such that the right function gets called.  What a pain.

The C 2011 standard added the `_Generic` keyword, which can make life a little easier in that respect:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SUMMATION_DEF(t) \
t summation_##t( t *values, size_t numValues ) \
{                                              \
  t result = 0;                                \
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < numValues; i++ )     \
    result += values[i];                       \
  return result;                               \
}

#define SUMMATION(x,s)  _Generic((x),                         \
                                 int *     : summation_int,   \
                                 double *  : summation_double \
                                )(x, s)

SUMMATION_DEF(int)
SUMMATION_DEF(double)

int main( void )
{
  int ivals[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  double dvals[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

  int sumi = SUMMATION(ivals, 5);
  double sumd = SUMMATION(dvals, 5);

  printf( "sumi = %d\n", sumi );
  printf( "sumd = %f\n", sumd );

  return 0;
}
```

The `_Generic` keyword allows you to evaluate expressions based on *types*; thus, if the *type* of the first argument to `SUMMATION` is `int *`, we call `summation_int`; it's it's `double *`, we call `summation_double`.  This way we don't have to specify the type name in the macro arguments.

The other approach, as you've seen, is to use `void *` and to delegate type-aware operations to other functions.  Like I said above, that's not really "generic" programming, since you have to manually implement each comparison function for each type.  You can't just code it once and be done with it.  And by using `void *`, you basically throw type safety out the window and into oncoming traffic.

And before anyone complains - no, none of these summation functions check for or deal with arithmetic overflow.  That's a subject for another day.

---

1. For sufficiently loose definitions of "easy".  The metaprogramming language used to support templates is Turing-complete, so you can do *really amazing* and impossible to understand things with it.

   For sufficiently loose definitions of "any type".  Note that whatever type you use must support the `+=` operator, otherwise the compiler will yell at you.

   This code *will* break for types like `unsigned int` or `long double` since they have whitespace in the name.  I don't immediately know the solution to that problem, and I've spent enough time on this answer as it is.